# Do all SQLAlchemy queries on autoloaded tables run after importing?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am autoloading database tables with `SQLAlchemy`:

```
# src/database/tables.py
from setup import engine
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base(engine)

class Address(Base):
    __table__ = Table('addresses', Base.metadata,
                      autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
class Doctor(Base):
    __table__ = Table('doctors', Base.metadata,
                      autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

I have query files where these table classes are imported and I try to create all the queries I'm going to use later iny my main `run.py` script:

```
# src/queries/addresses.py
from src.database.tables import Address, Doctor
from setup import session

join = (
    session.query(Address)
    .join(Doctor, Doctor.DoctorID == Address.ClientID)
)
...

# lots of additional declared queries
```

I have a `run.py` which imports the queries and creates pandas dataframe from them.

```
# run.py
import setup as stp
print('Prints instantly')
from src.queries import doctors, addresses
print('This prints only after a lot of time')
from src.methods import pandas_helper as pdh
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# creating dataframes from certain queries and plot them
```

Every time I run `run.py` even for a single `print('test')` after all the imports, the execution time becomes huge. I've put additional `print()` functions around the import of the query files to be sure that is where the process takes so much time.

I reckon the cause must be either the autoloading of the database tables from scratch or the numerous queries I've declared in the query files which are using these tables.

I'm not sure when the queries are run actually. I guess just after declaration, so when I import all the files all my queries within are instantly being called?

Is there a way to just create all these queries and table autoloads and run them only when I want to use that specific query variable which would need these resources?

Comment: Try adding `, echo=True` to your `create_engine` call to see what SQLAlchemy is sending to the database. FWIW, [this code](https://pastebin.com/pq0VRk31) produces exactly the same debug output whether or not the last line is commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of not seeing the wood for the trees situation. Yes, the declared query variables are all created when imported.

Simply putting all query variables into functions solves the problem. You have to call the function when needed, not importing tons of query variables.

```
# src/queries/addresses.py
from src.database.tables import Address, Doctor
from setup import session

def join(): 
    return (
        session.query(Address)
        .join(Doctor, Doctor.DoctorID == Address.ClientID)
    )
```

More like a basic Python problem in my head, but enlightening all the same.